# Collecting every word in document DOM tree with javascript

Tags: javascript, json, utf-8

Suppose you have a large document with around ~7000 words. I need to send all data to server.
I have no chance to use jquery, prototype etc. It should be clean OO javascript.
Sample page would be json russian page
I will exclude all tags and html markup from words.

My question is;

1. How can i collect/harvest all (utf8) words from document?

2. How can i convert the result to JSON data?

Thanks

Comment: Is the document pure text? Or are there HTML tags, etc.?

Comment: And how do you want the words to be sent? Each word separately, or the text as a whole?

Comment: Document is a html document. Sending data could be like;
{"words" : ["word1", "word2", "word3"]} etc.

Comment: Where is this HTML document located? User's harddrive another site, etc. Why are you doing it on the client and not the server?

Comment: html document located on the server. i have good reasons to do this on the client side :)

Comment: so you want only the words but no tag at all?

Comment: Surely yes. Suppose this page should be parsed; 
http://json.org/json-ru.html

Comment: smells a little like homework, no?

Answer (score 3):

This really doesn't seem like a job for Object Oriented programming. A sexy recursive function would work much better.

```
 var output=[];

 function scan(element) {
    var children=element.childNodes;
    for (var child in children){
        if (children[child].nodeValue) {
            output.push(children[child].nodeValue);
        }else {
            scan(children[child]);
        };
    };
 };

 scan(window.document.body);
```

This doesn't break the text up into individual words or even produce JSON, but it will give you a list of the individual words. You still need to do some cleanup on the text. In my 2 seconds of testing I found that it likes to display the text of everything including javascript and newlines (\n). Maybe if I feel like it I'll add more code. But this should get you going.

For turning it into JSON try Douglas Crockford's toJSON code. Just google it.

Comment: so simple. code organization not take in to account json data. it is not fit to question :) thank you anyway.

Comment: Thank you for link grandmaster. Youre da great as Houdini